# While I fetch site pages(.aspx) on sub sites using graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{subsite-id}/page it returns empty value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, sitepages, graph-api

I have a question:

Why get site pages(`.aspx`) on sub sites using `graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{subsite-id}/page` return value is empty,
While I used with `graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}` can return data?

I sure there's are site pages on the sub site.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all site pages in the site using below endpoint in Microsoft Graph:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/pages/microsoft.graph.sitePage
```

**Documentation**: [List SitePage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-list)

---

You can get the individual site pages details using below Microsoft Graph API call:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/pages/{page-id}/microsoft.graph.sitePage
```

**Documentation**: [Get SitePage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-get)

Make sure you are granting permissions like:

- Sites.Read.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried and failed, results are still empty :(

Comment: Are you using the correct site id? Are you getting any error? make sure you are using the correct site id where you have the site pages.

Comment: i am sure about site id and subsite id, when i use siteId  return values,which are the pages within the site, but when i use the subSiteId the site always returns empty. I don't know if there is any difference between site and subsite, eg configuration,...